# How to fix: npm ERR! Cannot find module 'read-package-json'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I made a horrible mistake and run this command:

```
sudo npm update -g npm
```

As a result npm was rendered useless, any attemps to install anything results in the following error :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/michaelb/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/node" "/Users/michaelb/.nvm/versions/node/v5.3.0/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.4
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'read-package-json'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Can anyone speculate what is the problem and how to fix it ?

Im using OS X El Capitan (10.11)

```
node -v
v5.3.0

npm -v
3.7.4

nvm ls
->       v5.3.0
default -> stable (-> v5.3.0)
node -> stable (-> v5.3.0) (default)
stable -> 5.3 (-> v5.3.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it with sudo?

Comment: yes, i get the same error using "sudo npm install"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found in their GitHub issues

[Reference:](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11618)

> Solution: Reinstall npm

Comment: I ended up doing just that, 
my npm was installed through nvm

mv ~/.nvm/ ~/.nvm-bkp;
nvm install 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my node was installed by the .pkg file. And I reinstall npm didn't work.
I solved this problem by **uninstall the node totally** follow this gist:
https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef

Answer (score 0):

***All npm issues such as :***

---

- Error: Cannot find module 'interpret'
- Error: Cannot find module 'read-pkg-up'
- Error: Cannot find module 'lru-cache'

---

***Solution***

---

1. Delete file :

> package-lock.json

2. Run in the terminal

> $npm upgrade